# How to split a multivalue cells into multiple rows using a VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to split cells into multiple rows without moving the cells in the ID column. The problem is that the list can be endless and the number of category's can be different and alose their can be information in column C which also have to stay on the same line as the ID cell.

Current and wanted results

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr4Rf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro to loop through your info and print it in the new columns. Something like:

```
Sub delimit()
Dim cat As Range, c As Range, i As Long, nxt As Long
Set cat = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("B2"), Range("B65000").End(xlUp))
For Each c In cat
    arr = Split(c.Value, ";")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        nxt = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        If i = 0 Then Range("D" & nxt).Value = c.Offset(0, -1)
        Range("E" & nxt).Value = arr(i)
    Next i
Next c
End Sub
```

[image]

The core thing we are using here is `Split()` which will turn a string into an array.
Syntax : `Split ( expression [,delimiter] [,limit] [,compare] )`

We loop through the category list, set to column "`B`", and make a new array for each cell.
Then we print this array in the column we want, in this example column "`E`".
But first, we print out the ID number in column "`D`", since we are currently aiming for that row.

If you also want to copy column "`C`" like we do "`A`", simply change the `IF` accordingly.

From

```
If i = 0 Then Range("D" & nxt).Value = c.Offset(0, -1)
```

to

```
If i = 0 Then
    Range("D" & nxt).Value = c.Offset(0, -1)
    Range("F" & nxt).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)
End If
```